# Все слетело после обновления

Tags: html, css

Я ничайно удалил строку но я ее востановил и когда обнавил бац и все цвета исчезли а контент весь влево сместился вот коды ааааа.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Стоматология - это сайт о стоматологических услугах">
<meta name="keyworlds" content="Стоматология, лечение зубов, зубы, стоматология />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>






    <div class="main">
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
<div class="logo_text">
    <h1><a href="/">Стоматология</a></h1>
    <h2>ИП Степанян Артур Ишханович</h2>
</div>



</div>

<div class="menubar">

<ul class="menu">
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
        <div class="films_block"></div>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/WOW.jpg"></a>
      </div>



</div>
















</div>





</div>                            
<div class="site_content">

 <div class="sidebar_container">

  <div class="sidebar_container">

                                                            <div class="sidebar">

                                                            <h2>Записаться на прием</h2>
                                                            <form method="post" action="#" id="search_form" >
                                                                <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="Имя" />
                                                                <input type="search" name="search_field" placeholder="Телефон" />
                                                                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="запись" />
                                                                </form>
                                                            </div>









</form>

</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Новости</h2>
    <span>01.07.2018</span>
    <p>Мы запустили расширенный поиск</p>
</div>



<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Адрес</h2>
    <span>MO, г.Химки, ул.Ленинградская, дом 1, 12 этаж</span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <h2>Контакты</h2>
    <span>+7 777 777 77 77</span>
    <p>+7 777 777 77 77</p>
</div>






<div class="posts">
        <h2>Как избавиться от страха перед лечением зубов?</h2>
        <ul>
            <p1>Если вы боитесь ходить к зубному врачу, если страх перед кабинетом стоматолога доводит вас до состояния ужаса, а при одном воспоминании о звуке бормашины вы готовы упасть в обморок, то возможно, что у вас дентофобия или боязнь зубных врачей. И, значит, эта статья написана именно для вас: вы узнаете, почему люди боятся стоматологов, как можно преодолеть этот страх и как правильно настроиться на поход к зубному врачу...</p1>
 <a href="#">читать</a>

        </ul>
      </div>








</div>



</div>








</div>



    </body>
    </html>


    <div class="footer">
   <p>
            <a href="#">Главная</a> |
            <a href="#">Услуги</a> |
            <a href="#">Галерея</a> |
            <a href="#">Отзывы</a> |
            <a href="#">О нас</a> 
   </p> 
   <p>
    wh-db.com 2018
   </p>


</div>






* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="search"] {
  color: #5d5d5d;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

input,
textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

h1,
h2 {
  font: normal 250% 'century gothic, arial';
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding: 15 0 5px 0;
  color: #000;
}

a,
a:hover {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul {
  margin: 2px 0 22px 17px
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;
  padding: 0 0 4px 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 140%;
}

.header {
  background-color: turquoise;
  height: 177px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
}

.main,
.logo,
.menubar,
.site_content,
.footer {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 880px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.logo h1,
.logo h2 {
  font: normal 300% 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 9px;
}

.logo_text h1,
.logo_text h1 a,
.logo_text h1 a:hover {
  padding: 22px 0 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em text-decoration: none;
}

{}

.logo h2 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 4px 0 0 0;
  color: #999
}

.menubar {
  width: 900px;
  height: 46px;
}

ul.menu {
  float: right;
}

sidebar {

}

.wrap {
    width: 500px;
    background: #555;
    height: 500px;
}
.left, .right {
    display: inline-block;
    //display: inline;
    //zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}



}

ul.menu li {}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1px 2px 0 0;
}

ul.menu li a {
  font: normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 35px 5px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu li.selected a {
  color: #aeb002;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
  color: #e4ec04;
}

.site_content {
  width: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.sidebar_container {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
   width: 100px;
   height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 198px;
  left: 5px;
}



.posts {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
   width: 500px;
   height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  left: 5px;
   color: black;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 224px;
  padding: 5%;
  margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  border: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.sidebar{
  float: left;
}

.btn {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  color: #136cb2;
}

.lables_passreg_text {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 2%;
}



.sidebar ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.sidebar .rating_sidebar {
  float: left;
}

.content {
  text-align: left;
  width: 620px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;

}

.content a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 28px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: turquoise;
  color: #a8aa94;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  min-width: 900px;
  top: 1000px;
}



.footer a {
  color: #a8aa94;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Используйте ctrl+z или ctrl+y, для перемещения по истории изменений. И хотелось бы узнать, в чем у вас конкретно вопрос?

Comment: Кавычки в метатеге на 7-й строке закрой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

забыли 2 закрывающие тега `</div>` для `<div class="main">` и `<div class="header">`

```
 <div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="logo_text">
        <h1><a href="/">Стоматология</a></h1>
        <h2>ИП Степанян Артур Ишханович</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menubar">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Галерея</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="films_block"></div>
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/img/WOW.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```